# How to set scopes when using default service account in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-platform, scopes

I am trying to use the sheets API via a service account. The code is working locally, however while hosting it in GAE, it is giving "insufficient scopes" error.

```
build = service('sheets','v4')
data = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id)
```

The default service account is being used in GAE and it has access to sheets API. I think this is arising because read scope(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly) is not mentioned in

```
build = service('sheets','v4')
```

Any idea what to do?